# Find object for given primary key in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, system.data.sqlite

I have a table "Customer" and its corresponding ORMapping Entity Customer in entity framework and I want to find an object corresponding to a given primary key.
Something like `customerObject.getObjectByID()` instead of a lambda expression or query.

Comment: yes but What I want is simply "select * from Customer where custId=2"

Answer (score 11):

```
var Customer = from c in datacontext.Customer
               where c.CustomerID == your_key
               select c;
```

That's assuming your customer table has a CustomerID column and that is the primary key.

Using DbSet's Find method:

```
Customer customer= db.Customer.Find(your_key);
```

Using a lambda expression:

```
 var customer= dataContext.Customer.Where(x=>x.CustomerID==your_key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was expecting just simple function call for example customerobject.getbjectByID()

Comment: Well, you could build a Extention Method and try to make the Lambda generic, maybe with an interface or something similar. Otherwise I am very pessimistic about it.

Answer (score 8):

"instead of lambda expression or query"

```
customerobject.Find(id);
```

More specifically:

```
var myDbSetTableEntity = context.MyDbSetTableEntity.Find(object key1, object key2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most compact way:

```
var myCustomer = myContext.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == wantedId);
```

wich is basically short-form for

```
myContext.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == wantedId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Other candidate selection methods are Single(), First() and FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Good to note that the short-form requires an import of System.LINQ by stating `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a composite key, build an object array and pass it to Find(). Eg:

```
try
{
    RECORD rec; // ie, your entity definition of a record (row)
    Object[] onePK = { id, s0, s1 };
    rec = YourEntities.RECORDs.Find(onePK);
    if (rec == null)
    {
        // handle the record-not-found situation
    }
}
catch (SystemException sex)
{
    string error = sex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for composite keys: `customerobject.Find(key1, key2, key3)`

what is order you specify the keys, assuming they are all strings ?